# Apply live effects on audio being played - swift for macOS

Tags: swift, macos, audio

It is now a few month that I'm experimenting the possibilities of audio manipulation on the mac via Xcode and swift.

I use AvFoundation's AvAudioEngine to apply audio effects and play an audio file. It is working fine but I would like to go one step further and apply theses effects to the audio being played on a specific audio device (with whatever application). I'am using two audio device (the first is 6in/6out, the second 2out) and would like to be able to select on which device are effects applied.

Is it possible to do that using AVAudioEngine? What about AvAudioMixerNode? Is it like a real mixer, with audio inputs, outputs, sends&returns, aux,..? What about AuGraph on the mac? Is it possible to combine two different classes to do the job?

I'm looking for examples but primarily more information on the general way audio programming works under macOS. 
Thank You.